# Creation of Task on Windows 7 remotely using Managed Wrapper

Tags: windows, task, wrapper, scheduler, managed

I am trying to create task in remote computer running on Windows 7 from client computer running Windows 7.   Is it possible? When I tried to do this I get following exception.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I am using following managed wrapper class.

TaskService ts = new TaskService("COMPUTERNAME", "remoteUserAcctName", "COMPUTERNAME", "remoteUserPassword");

As per this MSDN link, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766266.aspx , one can create task remotely connected to computers running Windows Server® 2008, Windows Vista®, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, or Windows 2000.

Comment: Quote: "must be a member of the Administrators group on the remote computer".  UAC elevation required.

Comment: The user I tried is already in administrator group and this time tried after changing to this UAC setting, 'Never notify me when Programs install software and try to change my computer'. Still getting same error.